# Generating two $-1$ correlated Poisson random variables with parameter $5$

Tags: stochastic-processes, monte-carlo

Is it possible to generate two random variables $X$ and $Y$ that are both $Poisson(5)$ with $Corr(X,Y)=-1$? Why?

I was thinking about generating $3$ independent Poisson random variables $Z_1,Z_2, and Z_3$ with parameter $5$. Then let $X\sim Z_1+Z_2$ and $Y\sim Z_1+Z_3$ are correlated Poisson random variables with parameter 5. Am I right? Then what should I do? Thank you.

Comment: Hint: If $X$ and $Y$ have correlation coefficient $-1$, there is a positive $a$, and a number $b$, such that $Y$ has the same distribution as $-aX+b$.

Comment: I don't get it. Why is that? Sorry about that.

Comment: It is a fact about correlation coefficient $-1$.

Comment: I wonder how to prove this fact. It wasn't obvious for me. Thank you. Other than that, I think I know how to prove it's impossible to generate 2 such random variables. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer below proves the key fact that if the correlation coefficient is $-1$, then there exist constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$, with $\alpha$ negative, such that $X=\alpha Y+\beta$ with probability $1$. Essentially we are proving the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, with particular attention to the equality case.

Let $U=X-\mu_X$ and $V=Y-\mu_Y$. Note that $U$ and $V$ have mean $0$. Also, the variance of $U$ is the same as the variance of $X$, and the same holds for $V$ and $Y$.
Consider $E((U+tV)^2)$, where $t$ is a variable. Note that
$$E((U+tV)^2)\ge 0. \tag{1}$$
for all $t$.

By the linearity of expectation, we have
$$E((U+tV)^2)=E(U^2)+2tE(UV)+t^2E(V^2).$$
Since this quadratic is always $\ge 0$, its discriminant is $\le 0$. It follows that $4(E(UV))^2-4E(U^2)E)V^2)\le 0$. This implies that $\frac{|E(UV)|}{\sqrt{E(U^2)}\sqrt{E(V^2)}}\le 1$.

But $\frac{E(UV)}{\sqrt{E(U^2)}\sqrt{E(V^2)}}$ is the correlation coefficient of $X$ and $Y$. We have proved the familiar fact that the correlation coefficient is between $-1$ and $1$.

The inequalities we have used are strict unless the quadratic $t^2E(V^2)+2tE(UV)+E(U^2)$ has minimum value of $0$.  Thus the only way we can have correlation coefficient $\pm 1$ is if there is a $t_0$ such that
$E((U+t_0 V)^2)=0$. Thus the only way we can have correlation coefficient $\pm 1$ is if there is a $t_0$ such that with probability $1$, we have $U+t_0V=0$.

Putting this in terms of $X$ and $Y$, the only way we can have correlation coefficient $\pm 1$ is if for some $t_0$, with probability $1$, we have
$$X-\mu_X+t_0(Y-\mu_Y)=0.$$
Equivalently, the correlation coefficient is $\pm 1$ is the exist constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that with probability $1$, we have 
$$X=\alpha Y+\beta.$$
The case correlation coefficient $-1$ corresponds to negative values of $\alpha$.

Comment: Why does this mean that it is impossible to generate a Poisson(5), Corr(X,Y)=-1?

Comment: @user151876:  Let $X$ be Poisson parameter $5$. If the correlation coefficient of $X$ and $Y$ is $-1$, then by the calculation above there is a $\beta$, and a negative $\alpha$ such that $Y$ has the same distribution as $\alpha X+\beta$. But $X$ takes on arbitrarily large values with positive probability. Let $n$ be such that $\alpha n+\beta\lt 0$. If $Y$ has the same distribution as $\alpha X+\beta$, then there is a negative $k=\alpha n+\beta$ such that $\Pr(Y=k)=\Pr(X=n)\gt 0$. But a Poisson $Y$ cannot take on a negative value with positive probability.